# Set Maximum Lines In Edit on mfc C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, line

I'm trying to set max line amount in an edit on c++ mfc application dialog and i'm actually having alot of trouble with it, You see i'm trying hard to find a way to set it i'm trying with SendMessage and can't find anything to change that amount also the max lines i can get is 14 and thats it. I need someone to help please!

Comment: You probably want to enable "vertical scroll" for the edit box. This will allow to enter unlimited lines. If you want to limit the lines, then disable vertical scroll, and change the edit box height. You also need to enable multi-line and want-return flag.

Comment: Thank you very much Barmak Shemirani it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreTranslateMessage` and detect if `RETURN` is pressed and then use `CEdit::GetLineCount` and if it is more that 14 prevent the message from processing.